# logstash to elasticsearch show Uknown setting

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, logstash

I just use very simple config which log the data from a file to elasticsearch.

Here is my config

```
input {
    file {
        path => "/var/log/logstash/logstash.log"
        start_position => beginning 
    }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
       protocol => "http"
   }
   stdout {}
}
```

and when I start logstash by

> ./bin/logstash -f /path/to/mycofig/i-file-o-es.conf

I get error

> Unknown setting 'protocol' for elasticsearch {:level=>:error}

I can make this config work by removing *protocol=>* so I think my plugin is installed correctly.

Anyone met this issue before? Thanks!

Comment: What version of logstash are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you're using Logstash 2.0 beta. In that latest version, they've revamped the [`elasticsearch` output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.0/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html) which now doesn't have any `protocol` setting anymore, since the [plugin defaults to using the `http` protocol](https://www.elastic.co/blog/logstash-2-0-0-beta1-released).

If you want to be able to specify the `protocol` setting (i.e. to use `node` or `transport` protocol), you need to use the new [`elasticsearch_java` output plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/2.0/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch_java.html)

Comment: One more quick question, are there any document showing the directories where those plugins are saved.

Comment: The plugins are all saved in the $ES_HOME/plugins directory.

Comment: @Val i think you mean `$LS_HOME/plugins`

Comment: I can't really the variable by `env|grep _HOME` , and my logstash folder only have `./bin/plugins`. Is there any default value of this?